# How to Search values Integer column alias in a WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to Filter values in where clause  alias variable,

```
CREATE TABLE BASE_Chq
(
ChequeInvoicePaymentId BIGINT NULL,
ChequeNumber VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
Amount MONEY NOT NULL
)
```

Once i select the whole table value i'm getting the result like below,

```
SELECT IIf(ChequeInvoicePaymentId IS NULL, 'OWN', 'PARTY') AS ChequeType, ChequeNumber, Amount
BASE_Chq
```

[image]

i want to filter Cheque Type wise but i'm getting error,

ERROR CODE:

```
SELECT IIf(ChequeInvoicePaymentId IS NULL, 'OWN', 'PARTY') AS ChequeType, ChequeNumber, Amount  
FROM BASE_Chq
WHERE (ChequeType = 'PARTY')
```

How to search using alias  column in where clause?

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot use an alias in your where clause**

Without questioning any parts of the query, you could do this:

```
SELECT IIf(ChequeInvoicePaymentId IS NULL, 'OWN', 'PARTY') AS ChequeType, ChequeNumber, Amount  
FROM BASE_Chq
WHERE (IIf(ChequeInvoicePaymentId IS NULL, 'OWN', 'PARTY') = 'PARTY');
```

A better approach would be directly filtering on the `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT IIf(ChequeInvoicePaymentId IS NULL, 'OWN', 'PARTY') AS ChequeType, ChequeNumber, Amount  
FROM BASE_Chq
WHERE ChequeInvoicePaymentId IS NOT NULL;
```

A small [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=476b9e0f66125de49aff3c5935690f38) example

---

**Why**

The filter in the `where` clause can be passed to the table as a (seek) predicate before computing the `IIF` function in the `SELECT`.

More info on this processing order in an [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d7b6971-11a0-4688-b228-f54d81b097c6/cant-access-the-alias-in-the-where-clauseusing-denserank?forum=transactsql) by Erland Sommarskog:

> You can't do that because a SELECT statement is computed in this
>   order:
>
> FROM-JOIN
>   WHERE
>   GROUP BY
>   HAVING
>   SELECT
>   ORDER BY
>
> So when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the aliases defined in the
>   SELECT list are not defined yet. ...